# OrganizationService throws authentication exception during RetrieveMultiple request

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I've a Post|sync|sandbox|Update Message CRM plugin for CRM online 2015, all works fine except `RetrieveMultiple` call

I've created `IOrganizationService`

```
    public static IOrganizationService GetOrganizationServiceByCurrentUser(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var serviceFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        var context = serviceProvider.GetService<IPluginExecutionContext>();
        return serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
    }
```

after call `RetrieveMultiple`

```
        Entity config = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(CrmConstants.Query.AzureCofig))
                                           .Entities.FirstOrDefault();
```

following error is appeared

> The authentication endpoint Username was not found on the configured
>   Secure Token Service!

I've tried to do the same thru unit test and `CrmConnection` all works fine. Looks like something wrong with plugin execution rights. Any idea?

Comment: looks like an issue with the ADFS configuration: http://help.clickdimensions.com/the-authentication-endpoint-username-was-not-found-on-the-configured-secure-token-service-error-when-registering/

including information on your deployment/environment would help diagnose the issue.

Comment: What happens if you do a "organizationService.Retrieve("systemuser", context.InitiatingUserId, new ColumnSet(true))";
That should return the current user info, if that works, there's something odd about you retrievemultiple and I Think it looks sort of funny, but that might be that surrounding code is missing :)

Comment: I've fixed the issue, it was a bug :) The entity is a custom config section so I had to call `RetrieveMultiple` under the system account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you retrieve any config sections you have to create IOrganizationService under the system account, not the user context

```
   public static IOrganizationService GetOrganizationServiceByCurrentUser(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var serviceFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        return serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
    }
```